# React multiple choice answer groups

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, radio-button, react-select

I'm working on a trivia game with answer groups (so question 1 has 4 choices, etc). I tried to get the answer choices to appear as radio buttons at first, then using React-Select (https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select).

When using radio buttons, I get 8 blank radio buttons. When using Select, I get the 8 answer groups but there's no text. I only know because I've been clicking to see what happens.

I suspect I'm not going into the arrays correctly and/or not binding something correctly, but my searches so far haven't yielded results. The text to the questions appears correctly, so I won't paste that below. I've included both radio and Select attempts to get insight into which one works best.

Repo: https://github.com/irene-rojas/pixar-react. Advice greatly appreciated.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Timer from "./Timer";
import Questions from "./Questions/Questions.js";

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (

    <div className="parallax">

    <div className="App">

    <div className="wrapper">


      <div className="header">
        <h1>Pixar Trivia!</h1>
      </div>

        <Timer />   

        <div className="questionSection">
          <Questions />
        </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Radio.js (this is my attempt at radio button answers. I'm only including 3 of the 8 answer groups to save space)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Radio extends Component {

  state = {
    answerChoices: [
        {answers1: [
            {
                label: "2001: A Space Odyssey",
                value: false
            },
            {
                label: "The Shining",
                value: true
            },
            {
                label: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest",
                value: false
            },
            {
                label: "The Godfather",
                value: false
            }
        ]},
    {answers2: [
            {
                label: "Luxo Ball",
                value: false
            },
            { 
                label: "Luxo",
                value: false
            },
            {
                label: "Luxo, Jr.",
                value: true
            },
            {
                label: "Tinny",
                value: false
            }
--------- skip to a 2 option group ------
        {answers7: [
            {
                label: "Boo",
                value: false
            },
            { 
                label: "Kitty",
                value: true
            }
            ]},
        ]
  };

  handleOptionChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");
    // checked={true}
  };

  render() {
    return (

      <div className="radio">

        <form>
            {this.state.answerChoices.map(answer => {
            return (
                <input 
                    type="radio" 
                    key={answer.id}
                    value={answer.value} 
                    defaultChecked={false}
                    onClick={this.handleOptionChange} 
                />
                )
            })}
        </form>

      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default Radio;
```

Answers.js (This is the React-Select attempt.)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const answerChoices = [

{answers1: [
    {
        label: "2001: A Space Odyssey",
        value: false
    },
    {
        label: "The Shining",
        value: true
    },
    {
        label: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest",
        value: false
    },
    {
        label: "The Godfather",
        value: false
    }
]},
{answers2: [
        {
            label: "Luxo Ball",
            value: false
        },
        { 
            label: "Luxo",
            value: false
        },
        {
            label: "Luxo, Jr.",
            value: true
        },
        {
            label: "Tinny",
            value: false
        }
]},
----------- skip to 2 option group ------
{answers7: [
    {
        label: "Boo",
        value: false
    },
    { 
        label: "Kitty",
        value: true
    }
]},
]

  class Answers extends Component {

    state = {
      selectedOption: null,
    }

handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
  this.setState({ selectedOption });
  console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
}

render() {
  const { selectedOption } = this.state;

  return (

        <Select
          value={selectedOption}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={answerChoices}
        />
      );
    }
  }

  export default Answers;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `answerChoices` is an array of objects that are also arrays, that means you need to iterate 2 times to be able to get to the answer options of each answer.

```
{this.state.answerChoices.map(answerOptions => {
        return answerOptions.map(option => (
           <input 
                type="radio" 
                key={option.id}
                value={option.value} 
                defaultChecked={false}
                onClick={this.handleOptionChange} 
            />
        ));
  }
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but when I make these changes, I get the error: "TypeError: answerOptions.map is not a function."

Comment: Curiously, the terminal says it compiled correctly and the background starts to load, then I get the error. The terminal continues to say it compiled correctly. I don't know if that's relevant but I wanted to provide as much info as I can.

Comment: @IreneRojas are you applying the changes in `Radio.js` ? This change I suggested if for the Radio buttons. The error you mention happens when `Array.map` when Array is not an array or is undefined.

Comment: Yes, I copied your suggestion exactly in Radio. Did I set up the state incorrectly in Radio?

Comment: Yes you are setting the initial state incorrectly in Radio.js you 
Need to define it inside the constructor of the class.
Ex:
```class Radio extends Component {
        constructor() {
           super();
           this.state = { ..../ the code /..... }
}```

Comment: Interesting. I was taught that constructor/super was no longer necessary in recent versions of React. I'll look into your suggestion. Or could it be a const before the component?

Comment: I ultimately decided to use the React-Select dependency rather than radio buttons. Thanks for asking.